# Python CSV Parse "§" Character

Tags: python, csv, encoding

I am trying to parse a `.csv` file containing the `§` character in python, such as this:

```
Name;Paragraph
Spam;§15
```

And the following code:

```
import csv
pathAndFileName = r"D:\Spam\test.csv"
with open(pathAndFileName, newline='') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
    csvObject= []
    for row in reader:
        csvObject.append(row)
    print(csvObject)
```

However, for some reason, it gets parsed like this:

```
[OrderedDict([('Name', 'Spam'), ('Paragraph', 'Â§15')])]
```

So, what apparently happens is that the `§` character gets parsed as `Â§`.

Is there a reason why this happens? And how can I work around it?

Comment: Probably not an issue with python. Make sure your terminal is using `utf8` encoding.

Comment: look for `utf8` encoding!

Comment: This is some kind of encoding issue. It may be that the file is encoded differently from how you expect, or it may be that Python produces output that is encoded differently from how your terminal expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `encoding='utf-8'`

example2.csv:

```
Name;Paragraph
Spam;§15
```

**Hence**:

```
import csv
pathAndFileName = r"example2.csv"
with open(pathAndFileName, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
    csvObject= []
    for row in reader:
        csvObject.append(row)
    print(csvObject)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[OrderedDict([('Name', 'Spam'), ('Paragraph', '§15')])]
```

Answer (score 2):

> So, what apparently happens is that the § character gets parsed as Â§

Well more or less, but it is anyway unrelated to csv parsing. It is just caused by an inconsistent encoding.

`'§'` is the unicode character U+00A7. It is encoded as `b'\xa7'` in Latin1 or windows cp1252, and as `b'\xc2\xa7'` in UTF-8.

And `b'\xc2\xa7'.decode('latin1')` just gives... `'Â§'`.

What can happen is:

1. the file is utf-8 encoded and you read it as latin1. Just declare the encoding:

   ```
   with open(pathAndFileName, encoding='utf8', newline='') as csvFile:
   ```
2. your Python environment outputs unicode data as UTF-8, while the terminal processes it as Latin1. Make sure that Python and the terminal use the same encoding. I'm sorry not to elaborate more, but it really depends on too many things, OS, terminal, environment variables, etc.